# MySQL query to count votes

Tags: mysql, subquery, inner-join

I have a table with the following columns: user_id, key, value, and flag. The SELECT, FROM, WHERE, GROUP BY and ORDER BY work by themselves as expected. It's when I try to add the key to the table, I get an errors that says to check my syntax. The key is the question and the value are the answers. I want a result that shows all the questions with all possible answers and a count of how often that answer occurred.

```
SELECT value AS 'Answer', count(*) AS 'Total Votes'
FROM survey_data sd
INNER JOIN (SELECT key FROM sd GROUP BY key) T1 ON T1.key = sd.key
WHERE flag != 1
GROUP BY value
ORDER BY 'Total Votes' DESC
```

What am I missing here?

As a side note, when I run this query without the INNER JOIN, the result is not ordered DESC by 'Total Votes' -- does anyone know why or what the problem might be?

Thanks,
Ryan

Answer (score 7, accepted):

key is a reserved word.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

put it within backticks (alt+96) or rename your field

edit. If you use an alias with more than one word you have to use backtick too.
So change your order by clause in

order by `total votes` desc without quotes

Put backtick before and after total votes. I don't see them in my post or even better change your field alias with a single word.

Answer (score 0):

Im an MSSQL guy so not sure if this will help, but try use fully qualified columns eg. table.column

```
SELECT sd.value AS 'Answer', count(sd.*) AS 'Total Votes'
FROM survey_data sd
INNER JOIN (SELECT sd.key FROM sd GROUP BY sd.key) T1 ON T1.key = sd.key
WHERE sd.flag != 1
GROUP BY sd.value
ORDER BY 'Total Votes' DESC
```